# How to use an input to call class function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
class People():
    def __init__(self, character_name, character_age):
        self.character_name = character_name
        self.character_age = character_age
    
    @classmethod
    def from_input(cls):
        return cls(input('Name: '), int(input('Age: ')))
    
    def introduce(self):
        print(f'Hey! I am {self.name}. I am {self.age}.')

search = input('Search: ')
search.introduce()
```

Obviously, `search.introduce()` doesn't work. What should I change to have the desired output?

Comment: `search = People.from_input()`.

Comment: Also, in `introduce` you need to use `self.character_name` and `self.character_age` instead of `self.name` and `self.age`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must apply the following changes:

```
class People():
def __init__(self, character_name, character_age):
    self.character_name = character_name
    self.character_age = character_age

@classmethod
def from_input(cls):
    return cls(input('Name: '), int(input('Age: ')))

def introduce(self):
    print(f'Hey! I am {self.character_name}. I am {self.character_age }.')

search = People.from_input()
search.introduce()
```